# Creating T-SQL user Groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created a User called Student and Teacher that can login into the Db and they have a default db. Is there a way that I can have it set up so that I can add multiple users but they all have the same permissions as a group.

```
Students
--> Bob
--> Jill
--> Steeve
```

Students can only Execute Stored Procedures.

Is there a way to do that?

It would be better than having to set all the permissions of each student for every stored procedure that I have for students to execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term is `role`. You create the role, grant it applicable rights, and then add users to that role.

```
CREATE ROLE students
GRANT EXECUTE TO students

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'students', 'Bob'
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'students', 'Jill'
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'students', 'Steve'
```